# Widgets overriding borders in Qt 4

Tags: qt, qt4, border, css

I have big problems concerning border sizes and content overrriding it.

Here is an example:

[image]

The container widget has this setting in stylesheets:

```
background: transparent;
border-style: solid; 
border-width: 13px 15px 15px 13px;
border-image: url(:/resources/images/info_msg_bg.png) 13 15 15 13 fill repeat;
```

The border has aproximately 15px aroung the circle image which is the reference:

[image]

So it expands vertically and horizontally to hold the text.

I did:

```
setMargin(0);
setSpacing(0);
setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
```

to the containing layout and see what happened: There is no margin on the left and right, no matter what border it had. Weird thing.

But i want it to happen on the top and bottom. But i´m never able to insert things on the top left corner and override the border size to take advantage of that space as it is happening on the left and right.
That makes me change strategy and make a not-rounded box, which i don´t like.

So my question is: 
**How can i set round borders using images (not border-radius property)... and place objects OVER the border zone?.**

Thanks

Comment: I've read your question a few times and I'm a bit puzzled about what you're trying to do, "and place objects OVER the border zone?" can you explain that a bit more as it's not immediately apparent what result you need.

Comment: If you set a 5 px border (border-image: url... 5 5 5 5 fill repeat; border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px;) you have a margin with an image, for example round corners with images. But if you want to add elements over the images in the borders. For example, something round just over the round border, so you add a round button to push there, it´s not possible, because you have a 5x5 border there that pushes out the button widget!

Comment: The best example is here, in my other post that was forgotten long ago and still no answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166670/qt-border-transparency-and-padding-how-to-create-this-effect
If that is part of the border image, how the hell can you put the button in there? OVERRIDING the border image? Negative margin or padding doesn´t work. Keeps the border zone.

Comment: Right, I see what you're trying to do. With the way Qt's widget model is setup if you're adding a widget into a widget it exists within the confines of the box model so trying to force an overflow isn't really workable (in my experience). For a level of customisation like that using QPainter and building it from scratch would be easier but I see you're looking to avoid that solution.

Comment: Thanks!. That´s what i was thinking. But suddenly i found another custom widget i did (rewriting its paint event with what they say you have to add for custom widgets using stylesheets) long ago that has a 37px bottom border, and still works like if it had just a 5px margin! How come this happens?

Comment: Without seeing the code I wouldn't be able to say 100%, but I'd imagine it's calculating the content boundary differently than a stock and standard widget would.

Comment: But why?. Making your own custom widget makes this work?. Ill investigate, one of my next steps will be investigate that, and i´ll come back. I´ll add the code when i have some time. Thanks.